# Where can i manage / revoke / amend etc.. Trello API keys?

Tags: trello

Where can i manage / revoke / amend etc.. Trello API keys ?

I can see where i can make a new key, but cant see where to manage / revoke / amend etc..

Answer (score 2):

To get your key go to https://trello.com/app-key/

#### Revoke your token

**Step 1.** Go to *Applications* on your *Account Settings* Page

**Step 2.** Click revoke!